# Sql rating issue

Tags: php, sql, database, rating

Here's my code. My problem is that I want the insertion to happen just when the `rating_airlines` value is between `1` and `5` but it keeps adding all the values.

`rating_airlines` is `varchar` on my database.

```
<?php
    require_once('connect.php');

    mysql_select_db($database_localhost,$con);

    $nom_airlines=$_GET['nom_airlines'];
    $rating_airlines=$_GET['rating_airlines'];
    $a=intval($rating_airlines);

    if($a=1 || $a=2 || $a=3 || $a=4 || $a=5 ) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Airlines(nom_airlines,rating_airlines)
        VALUES ('$nom_airlines','$a') ");

        echo "OK";}
    else {
        die('Requête invalide : ' . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not comparing the values you are setting. Single equals sets double compares.

```
if($a=1 || $a=2 || $a=3 || $a=4 || $a=5 )
```

Should be

```
if($a==1 || $a==2 || $a==3 || $a==4 || $a==5 )
```

But could even be

```
if($a>=1 && $a <=5 )
```

You also should switch from the mysql to mysqli or PDO. [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Also note that by passing `$nom_airlines` directly to your query you are open to injections at a minimum use the mysql_real_escape_string.

```
$nom_airlines=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nom_airlines']);
```

Comment: Bonus for the injection warning.

Answer (score 0):

You are using assigning operator . You need to use equality here.

```
if($a==1 || $a==2 || $a==3 || $a==4 || $a==5 ) {
```

Take a look into these 2:

[Assignment Operators in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

[Equality Operators in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Moreover,

```
$a = $b     Assign      Sets $a to be equal to $b.
$a == $b    Equal       TRUE if $a is equal to $b.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type. (introduced in PHP 4)
```